# When a power of a prime ideal is not a primary Ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, quotient-spaces, nilpotence

Take the ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^3-y^3-z^3)$. I want to find a prime ideal, $p$, where $p^3$ is not a primary ideal. Any suggestions how to find such a prime ideal?

I tried a few, like $(x,z)$, $(xy-z)$, $(y^2)$, and $(xyz)$ (and more) but can't find anything. I think I need to find a prime ideal such that it's third power will eliminate one of the cubes in the quotient, but not certain.

The wiki on prime ideals give the example of $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$, but I've found this is a vveerryy different ring than the one I am looking at.

Any advice or hints welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694646/is-there-an-example-of-a-power-of-prime-ideal-in-a-polynomial-ring-that-is-not-p?rq=1).

Comment: I adjusted your title because it misrepresented your problem before.

Comment: Thank you for the post, it looks interesting. Appreciate that. And thank you for adjusting my title, you're right this fits the idea much better, appreciate your edit!

Comment: Probably @DietrichBurde’s suggestion is relevant to your question. I do not think the ideals you listed are prime. Do you mind trying the ideal generated by x-y and z?

Comment: @Youngsu said suggestion is probably relevant, but I can't seem to crack its transferability to my question. The problem I am facing is coming up with these prime ideals, which all examples (the suggested as well) just pulls these ideals out of thin air - sort of what I am doing by guessing. I tried your suggestion of $(x-y,z)$ and found the corresponding quotient space is $C[x,y,z]/(x^3,y^3,z^3,x^2y,x^2z,xy^2,y^2z,xz^2,yz^2,xyz)$ which I can't find a zero divisor in either? Unless I am blind, which to this kind of maths I am a bit... Thanks for your feedback